# Check mysql data with android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I got a strange (at least for me) problem.
I want to check if an email address, that's on an android device is already in my database.
I got this code on my server side:

```
<?php
include('db_connect.php');
$db = new _DB_Connect();
$db->connect();

    if(isset($_POST['email'])){

        $accountMail = $_POST['email'];
        $result = mysql_query("select email from gcm_users;");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if($row['email'] == $accountMail){
                echo "E-Mail found";
            }else{
                echo "Not found";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I post the account email with android to the file.
I the mail IS in the database I get the echo "E-Mail found" and could see it on my android.
If the E-Mail IS NOT in the database, I see nothing.
Heres the function I use on my android so far:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try{
        String accountMail;
        InputStream inputStream;
        String status;
        //get Account e-mail
        accountMail = RegisterDeviceOnRaspberryPiServer.getAccount(context);

        //testoutput
        System.out.println("Found Mail is: -> " + accountMail);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://checkRegistration.php");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", accountMail));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        status = RegisterDeviceOnRaspberryPiServer.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        System.out.println("STATUS: " + status);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

So like I said, the STATUS: + status print gives me only a response, when the mail is inserted, but none when theres nothing in the DB.

The second question is, is there maybe a better way to check, whether an account e-mail is in my database or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the problem is the while loop condition.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

the code inside this loop will only run if there is at least 1 result (this is because the mysql_fetch_array returns false for empty result sets).

in the event where there are no emails, the condition is false and the code inside the loop is skipped. That is why you are seeing nothing when an email doesn't exist

2) I don't think you have to worry about the best possible solution to this problem. You are very close. The simplest solution I can think of doesn't need a while loop. you can just use the count variable you declared above the while loop. If the number of rows returned from your query (count) is = 0, the email doesnt exist, Else it exists.

Optional extra: If you wanted to check for duplicate email entries in your db you could check if count > 1

Tangent: I ran into similar problems when using an SQLite db for local storage. Basically, when you query the SQLite database, your result is a Cursor object that contains all the rows and data. Cursor has a method just like the one you used in the while loop. It is easy to forget it's weird behavior in the event the Cursor object is empty

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it?
In my case I am checking if a `phone_number` exists in my database.

checkPhoneNumber.php

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    include("classes/PDO.class.php");
    $db = new DatabaseHelper();
    $conn = $db->connect();

    //API JSON REQUEST
    $json_req = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $phone_number = $json_req->{"phone_number"};

    //JSON Return
    $return = array();

    $query = "SELECT phone_number FROM user WHERE phone_number = :number";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":number", $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($stmt->execute()){

        $phone_number = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(is_array($phone_number)){

            $return = array("result" => TRUE, "message" => "Number is registered");

        }else{
            $return = array("result" => FALSE, "message" => "Number is not registered");

        }

    }else{

        $return = array("result" => FALSE, "message" => "An error occurred executing the database query");

    }

    echo json_encode($return);

}else{

    //Nothing

}
```

As you can see I am accepting the request `phone_number` in **JSON** format.

In my android App I use something this:

```
private class CheckUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private String apiUrl;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String result;
    private boolean isRegistered;

    public CheckUser(String apiUrl, String phoneNumber) {

        this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            // HTTP Client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);

            // DATA TO SEND
            JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
            request.put("phone_number", phoneNumber);

            // ENTITY
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request.toString());

            // PARAMS
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // RESPONSE
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            printLog("checkUser API " + response.getStatusLine());

            // RESULT DATA
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        try {

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);
            isRegistered = data.getBoolean("result");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isRegistered;
    }

}
```

I make the HTTP request sending JSON data because my API accepts JSON only, **see above**

Hope it helps